# Add EventFilter via fxml

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

now i can do this

```
public TextField lastmonthbox;
public void initialize()throws Exception{
    lastmonthbox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle( KeyEvent t ) {
            char ar[] = t.getCharacter().toCharArray();
            char ch = ar[t.getCharacter().toCharArray().length - 1];
            if (!(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' || ch=='.')) {
                System.out.println("The char you entered is not a number");
                t.consume();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

is there way to add eventfilter via fxml, looks like onAction="#someFunction"??

i not found any list or tutorial about all possible tags in fxml(

Comment: The documentation for FXML is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html). It's not possible to make a comprehensive list of tags, because arbitrary classes (including classes you write) can be instantiated with FXML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK No but you can always customize the controls according to your needs. For example like

```
<MyTextField ... onKeyTypedFilter="#yourFilter" />
```

then do some reflection staff in backend. However is it worth?

Comment: I don't think that would need any reflection, would it? Just an `ObjectProperty<EventHandler>` and a change listener on the property that added and removed event filters. But probably not worth it anyway.

Comment: @James_D "#yourFilter" is a String and so you need reflection to find the method/field by the name from the instance class.

Comment: The FXMLLoader already does that... It's not useful, but perhaps an interesting academic exercise: https://github.com/james-d/CustomOnEventFilter/tree/master/src/customoneventfilter

Comment: @James_D, good job! It seems you have followed the original approach of JavaFX. Post your link as answer, sure it will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following Uluk's answer, you can do something like [this](https://github.com/james-d/CustomOnEventFilter/tree/master/src/customoneventfilter). There's no reflection required as the FXMLLoader already takes care of converting "#..." to an EventHandler object.

Note that this is just the structure: this isn't a particularly robust way of creating a numeric-only text field. For example, the user can copy and paste arbitrary text in there, using either keystrokes or the mouse.